# JWT token authorization on the c# server side not clear

Tags: c#, jwt

I have a github project [link](https://github.com/cornflourblue/aspnet-core-3-signup-verification-api) where the client sends `Authorization` header to the server containing the JWT token like below. What I can't understand is how on the server side `[Authorize(Role.Admin)]`can understand the `Role.Admin` which is application specific enum value (belonging to the account object - details beow).

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // add auth header with jwt if account is logged in and request is to the api url
        const account = this.accountService.accountValue;
        const isLoggedIn = account && account.jwtToken;
        const isApiUrl = request.url.startsWith(environment.apiUrl);
        if (isLoggedIn && isApiUrl) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${account.jwtToken}` }
            });
        }

        return next.handle(request);
    }
```

On the server side I have middleware class containing the code that decripts the token like this:

```
try
            {
                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret);
                tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    // set clockskew to zero so tokens expire exactly at token expiration time (instead of 5 minutes later)
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                }, out SecurityToken validatedToken);

                var jwtToken = (JwtSecurityToken)validatedToken;
                var accountId = int.Parse(jwtToken.Claims.First(x => x.Type == "id").Value);

                // attach account to context on successful jwt validation
                context.Items["Account"] = await dataContext.Accounts.FindAsync(accountId);
            }
            catch 
            {
                // do nothing if jwt validation fails
                // account is not attached to context so request won't have access to secure routes
                Console.WriteLine("Failed");
            }
```

So on the server side I have controller that has `[Authorize(Role.Admin)]` annotation like below which I can't understand - how `Authorize` can understand the `Role:Admin` - which is application specific - is it via introspection?

```
[Authorize(Role.Admin)]
        [HttpGet("all-dates")]
        public ActionResult<ScheduleDateTimeResponse> GetAllDates()
        {
            var dates = _accountService.GetAllDates();
            return Ok(dates);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project has a [custom AuthorizeAttribute](https://github.com/cornflourblue/aspnet-core-3-signup-verification-api/blob/master/Helpers/AuthorizeAttribute.cs) for which the Role enumeration is in scope. This differs from the [standard attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizeattribute) from the BCL. This attribute implements [`IAuthorizationFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.iauthorizationfilter) which the asp.net middleware understands must be invoked against this controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the application is referring to some kind of authentication service before the call endpoint. You should be able to see it in the console logs.

Check in solution nugets if there is no some kind of company aut service package

Ofc if you are sure that role is not a part of JWT token.
you can check that with: https://jwt.io/

Sorry...but I cannot add just simply comment yet...